# There should be "difference between" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I guess there should be "difference between" tag for comparing terms.

Am I correct?

Comment: "Difference between" should be disallowed in questions. (Also "Why is ... ?) It's a (lazy) pretend question. The asker asks about multiple things. If they don't know what they are, why are they asking for "the difference"? They should find out what each is. If they think they know what they are, how is it that they need "the difference"? And what does that even mean? Almost always an abstraction is needed--but which? Either way they should give definitions/characterizations, show & apply research & ask 1 clear concise researched non-duplicate question re how they are stuck on a specific point.

Answer (score 13):

No, such a tag should not exist on Stack Overflow. It would be an example of a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) because it does not describe the content of the question. Instead, the question should be tagged with the technologies that you are actually asking about.

Furthermore, such questions do not seem like they would be [practical programming questions, within the scope of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yet it seems to exist with 1600+ questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/difference